# List files that satisfies Rsync Filter

Tags: arrays, filter, path, rsync, librsync

Given a rsync filter file that looks something like this, is there a way to list all files in the directory that satisfy the filter?

```
+ /var/lib/hello/samba/*
- /var/lib/world/sdfs/
- /var/lib/world/staging/
- /var/lib/world/uml/
+ /var/lib/world/**
```

Is there a way to check if a specific path string satisfies the filter? For instance, the input path string could be /var/lib/hello/samba/file1 or /var/lib/world/dir1 or /var/lib/world/file2

Comment: Why not just run `rsync -nv ... /the/test/file /tmp` and see if it would copy or not?

Answer (score 1):

In order to list the files that are to be tracked, make a call to rsync without specifying the destination. For instance, something like

```
rsync --recursive --filter='merge rsync_filter_file' source_dir
```

You could also try looking into the dry-run argument available for rsync.